# How to start an executable jar from spring-boot with procrun windows service executor?

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, procrun

I created a `runnable jar` using `spring-boot-maven-plugin`.
The jar can be run using `jar -jar %FILENAME%`.

But I'd like to install it as a `windows` service using `procrun`.

Problem: when I then start the app, I get the following output:

```
[2016-12-05 12:33:22] [info]  [ 7788] Starting service...
[2016-12-05 12:33:23] [error] [ 4856] FindClass de/app/MyApplication failed
[2016-12-05 12:33:23] [error] [ 7788] Failed to start Java
[2016-12-05 12:33:23] [error] [ 7788] ServiceStart returned 4
[2016-12-05 12:33:23] [info]  [ 7916] Run service finished.
[2016-12-05 12:33:23] [info]  [ 7916] Commons Daemon procrun finished
```

If I rename the file to *tar.gz I can see there is no directory "de/app/". But a `BOOT-INF/classes/de/app` directory.

The question is: why is the app startable by using `java -jar`, but not as the procrun service (which should basically do the same)?

Comment: Spring Boot has its own launcher, so no it is not doing the same as `procrun `. When using `java -jar` Spring boot has its own launcher and classpath mechanism to be able to cope with the file format. How to start a spring boot application as a windows service is (sparsely) documented in [the reference guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/deployment-install.html#deployment-windows). You should be using `winsw` instead of `procrun`.

Answer (score 2):

Kind of late to the show, but in case anyone stumbles across this problem:

The fat jar files generated by spring contain wrapped dependencies. If you want to run them through procrun, you can do so by calling `org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher`

So when creating your service, try this:

```
prunsrv //IS/Myservice --Classpath="C:\my-fat.jar" --StartClass="org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher"
```

This is the equivalent of running `java -jar my-fat.jar`

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, Spring Boot starting from 1.4.0.RELEASE has a changed fat jar packaging which is closer to WAR packaging.

Issue described [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/6812).

As a solution you can try to add a classifier to the maven execution like described [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/6792#issuecomment-243564648), or just change to an older version of Spring Boot.

Hope this helps!

Comment: As I don't want to downgrade: I tried adding the `classifier`, anyways the jar shows the same error.

Comment: You can try to downgrade to see if that's the error or not.

Comment: Hm I tried `1.3.8.RELEASE`, which generates a `jar` with the correct path. Anyways I get the same error even though I can see the class in the correct folders.